# C - [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c

There's a bunch of threads about C++, but I'm stuck with regular C here and can't find an answer anywhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char word[26], letter, reverse[26], length;
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);

    length=strlen(word);
    for (int i=0; i<=length; i++) {
        letter = word[length-i];
        strcpy(reverse, letter);
        printf("%c\n", reverse);
    }

    getch();
}
```

I'm getting errors as the title states.

> 13    25  ~   [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
>   [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
> 51    18  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\string.h  [Note]
> ```
>
> initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'

What the code should do is reverse the written word and type it out line by line, by each last letter.
Etc. - Type in "food" and the program should output:

d

od

ood

food

I know I messed up somewhere in the 'letter', but I have no clue how to fix it.
Also I'm trying to avoid using std::, personal prefrence.

Comment: The message seems clear. `letter` is not a `char *` as required (ie, not a string). It is a single `char`.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between a `char` and a string. In C, a string is an array of `char`. And the `strcpy` function expects two strings as arguments.

Comment: More specifically, in C a string is a _null-terminated_ array of `char`s.

Comment: @Tremmert: You want to push `letter` onto the beginning of `reverse`?

Comment: If it still isn't clear, when you declare `char word[26]`, `word` is a pointer to the first character in a 26 character array. *It is a pointer already*. So when you need to provide a pointer to `scanf`, it is simply `scanf("%s", word);` (no `&` before `word`). Also **always** check the **return** of `scanf` to validate a successful conversion.

Comment: do not `#include` header files those contents are not used:  I.E. `conio.h`

Comment: the function `main()` only has a very small number of valid return types (regardless of what Visual Studio allows) in the current scenario the signature for `main()` should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value, not the parameter value, to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer so as to avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, which can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 26.  Strongly suggest using a `#define` or `enum` statement to give those magic numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: using the function: `getch()` is not portable.  Suggest using: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch ); getchar();`

Comment: this line: `strcpy(reverse, letter);` is nonsense.   The contents of `letter` is a single character and the function: `strcpy()` expects the second parameter to be a pointer.

Comment: @user3629249 putting all this in an answer would have been easier and imho the better place (plus you get rewards for it)

Comment: @KamiKaze, other than the comment about `strcpy()`, none of the comments answer the OPs question.  So they should not be used as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main( void ) {
    char word[26], reverse[26];
    int length, i;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);   
    length=strlen(word);

    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        reverse[i] = word[length - i - 1];
    }

    /* Put \0 to terminate the string */
    reverse[length]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", reverse);
}
```

Note that in the for loop you have to use only `<` and not `<=` because you'll get out of bounds of the array (negative index) and you have to put the `\0` terminator to terminate your reverse string. You don't need `letter` and btw `strcpy` works not with single chars, since a single char is not a string (because of the missing string terminator (`\0`)).

Edit:

```
int main( void ) {
    char word[26], reverse[26];
    int length, i;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);   
    length=strlen(word);

    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        reverse[i] = word[length - i - 1];

        /* Put \0 to terminate the string */
        reverse[i + 1]='\0';
        printf("%s\n", reverse);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see this one and therefore posted a nearly identical answer. Have an up-vote.

Comment: It works well, but what I require is the 'reverse' being outputted multiple times, +1 letter at a time. So "food" should get output as
d
od
ood
food
Thank you for the code, I'll work with it. Still getting all the quirks of C.

Comment: In that case just move the printf line at the end of the `for` loop and don't forget to add the terminating `\0` before you call the printf: `reverse[i + 1]='\0';`

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You pass the address of an array to scanf, rather than passing the array.
- You don't copy the null termination correctly.
- strcat must have null terminated strings as parameters, it cannot work with single characters. You don't need to use it here anyway.

Fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) 
{
  char word[26];
  char reverse[26]; 
  size_t length;
  size_t i;

  printf("Enter word: ");
  scanf("%s", word);

  length=strlen(word);
  for (i=0; i<length; i++) 
  {
    reverse[i] = word[length-i-1];
  }
  reverse[i] = '\0';

  printf("Reverse: %s\n", reverse);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter word: stackoverflow
Reverse: wolfrevokcats
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of errors in the code. The one that you are asking about is due to the fact that you are passing a `char` (i.e. the variable `letter`) rather than the address (i.e. `&letter`)

This "fix" would cause the compiler error to disappear, however it would cause another one to appear. This is because we'd now be passing a pointer to a `char` rather than a pointer to a terminated string.

```
for (i=0 ; i<26 ; i++)
    reverse[i] = word[25-i];
```

Comment: Sorry, but replacing one problem with another is not an answer.

Comment: Giving a wrong answer and then saying why it is wrong is still not an answer. Just don't go there. Go straight to a fully correct answer.

Comment: Read my comment to the question above.

Answer (score -4):

Here i have to pass in strcat(char * s1, const char * s2);
Here reverse is the cha* and &letter is const char*.
Check out this one.

this is the code what you want as output.

```
int main()
{
    char word[26], letter, length;
    int n, c, d;

    char reverse[26];
    char temp[26];
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    length=strlen(word);
    for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)
        {
            letter = word[length-i];
            strcat(reverse, &letter);
            n = strlen(reverse);
            for (c = n - 1, d = 0; c >= 0; c--, d++)
            temp[d] = reverse[c];
            temp[d] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

[image: Your Output]

Comment: this is just plain wrong. reverese is an array so 'reverse' already is the address of the array, no need for '&'. And letter is still not a string just a pointer to a char.

Comment: than why it will gives an error in code.? @KamiKaze

Comment: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & 
this what my IDE suggested. @KamiKaze
First make sure you are right after that give suggestion

Comment: `strcat()` expects address to the 1st element of a C-"string", that is a `0`-terminated array of `char`.

Comment: So why my IDE suggest me to do like this @alk. And it will gives me the right answer also.

Comment: you just have to modify the second argument. The first one is okay as it is. The clue is here 'initializing argument 2 of `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)`. Don't know about your IDE, but I prefer reading the API and work with it than what some heuristic suggest might be right. As I said `reverse` already is an address, you could do `&reverse[0]` if it satisfies you. Insert snarky remark about your remark here....

Comment: `strcat` must get null terminated strings as parameters, you cannot pass single chars. If this program "seems to work" it is because of sheer luck.

Comment: @KamiKaze: "*The first one is okay as it is*" just to avoid misunderstandings: `char reverse[26]; ... strcat(reverse, ...):` is okay.  Doing `strcat(&reverse, ...` is not.

Comment: @alk I should have been clearer, the first argument is good in the original code. Thx for clarifying this.